# How to display the multiple locations in map control(windows phone 8.1)

Tags: c#, json, google-maps, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

I am trying to develop an application in windows phone 8.1 with a map control. Google place api is used to get the nearby locations in the Json format. Now how to display them to my map control in windows phone application.

When I extract the Json format I got the below classes.

```
 public class Location
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Northeast
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Southwest
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Viewport
    {
        public Northeast northeast { get; set; }
        public Southwest southwest { get; set; }
    }

    public class Geometry
    {
        public Location location { get; set; }
        public Viewport viewport { get; set; }
    }

    public class OpeningHours
    {
        public bool open_now { get; set; }
        public List<object> weekday_text { get; set; }
    }

    public class Photo
    {
        public int height { get; set; }
        public List<string> html_attributions { get; set; }
        public string photo_reference { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
        public string icon { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string place_id { get; set; }
        public string reference { get; set; }
        public string scope { get; set; }
        public List<string> types { get; set; }
        public string vicinity { get; set; }
        public OpeningHours opening_hours { get; set; }
        public List<Photo> photos { get; set; }
        public double? rating { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<object> html_attributions { get; set; }
        public string next_page_token { get; set; }
        public List<Result> results { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
    }
```

So I want to display every location in my map control with a pushpin.

[image]

In Geometry we have latitute and logitude values.How to place them in my map control

Answer (score 1):

you have to do something like this first of all make two lists and pass locations to it   like that

```
        public List<string> longt = new List<string>();
        public List<string> lati = new List<string>();
```

then for loop to show many icons on map like that

```
for (i = 0; i <=t.Longitudelist.Count-1 ; i++)
            {

                MapIcon mapIcon1 = new MapIcon();
                string latitudetxt;
                string longitudetxt;
                latitudetxt = t.Latitudelist[i].Text;
                longt.Add(latitudetxt);
                longitudetxt = t.Longitudelist[i].Text;
                lati.Add(longitudetxt);
                // mapIcon1.Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png"));
                mapIcon1.Location = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
                {

                   Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(longt[i]),
                   Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(lati[i])
                });
               // mapIcon1.Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png"));
                mapIcon1.NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
                Map.MapElements.Add(mapIcon1);

                var bt = new Button();
                buttonn.Add(bt);
                bt.Content = "";
                bt.Width = 30;
                bt.Height = 50;
                bt.Opacity = 10;
                bt.Content = i;
                 // button.
                this.Map.Children.Add(bt);
                // assign geoposition
                var position = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
                {
                    Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(longt[i]),
                    Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(lati[i])

                });
                MapControl.SetLocation(buttonn[i], position);
                var pointt=MapControl.GetLocation(bt);
                pointt.Position.Latitude.ToString();
                pointt.Position.Longitude.ToString();
                //longg= position.Position.Latitude;
                //latt = position.Position.Longitude;
              //  button.Tag = longg;

                MapControl.SetNormalizedAnchorPoint(bt, new Point(0.5, 0.5));
                MapControl.SetIsTemplateFocusTarget(bt, true);

                bt.Click += Button_Click;

                await Map.TrySetViewAsync(mapIcon1.Location, 18D, 0, 0, MapAnimationKind.Bow);

            }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should start with watching this tutorial 
https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-1/12

Comment: There are multiple locations.I want to display all locations which is present in the Geometry class -> Locations -> latitude and logitude values in my map control

Comment: And? Video shows you how to add items on map. What else do you need?

Comment: Instead of whole pasting tutorial (link), only best solution might have been better